# Creating string in C

Tags: c, arrays, string, strcat, itoa

I'm trying to create in Texas Instrument CCS a string in C like this : `{steps: nSteps}` in order to send it as a json, `nSteps` is an `int` .I want to convert into a string as well with the following code:

```
    void jsonSteps(char* stepstr, int steps)
{
    char x[3];
    const char s1[10], s3[10];
    char s2[10];
    itoa(steps,x,10);
    s1[]="{steps:";

    s3[]="}";
    s2 = strcat(s1, x);
    stepstr = strcat(s2, s3);

}
```

I have this error in

```
s1[]="{steps:";
```

and

```
s3[]="}";
```

I receive an error

> "#29 expected an expression"

and also

> " #169-D argument of type "const char *" is incompatible with parameter of type  "

Comment: That just doesn't look like C code. You can't just make things up and expect them to work.

Comment: Sure you can `atoi`... `atoi`...`atoi`...`itoa`...BINGO!

Comment: Which book are you reading? What does your book say about `sprintf`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
s1[]="{steps:";
```

You can't change an array to be at some other address, so this line of code doesn't make any sense. You probably want `strcpy (s1, "{steps:");` to copy that string into the array.

```
s3[]="}";
```

Same problem. You can't set an array equal to the address of a string. Arrays don't have a single value you can set to anything. You probably want `strcpy (s3, "}");` to copy that string into the array.

```
s2 = strcat(s1, x);
```

You are trying to change `s2` itself here. I'm not sure what you're intending here, but that can't possibly work. Maybe you want `strcpy(s2, s1); strcat(s2, x);`? If so, I think you'll run out of space since you only allocated 10 characters for s2.

```
stepstr = strcat(s2, s3);
```

What's the point of setting the value of a variable that's about to go out of scope?

You really just need to learn C, there's no other way to put it.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you cannot `assign` arrays in c. So,

```
s1[]="{steps:";
```

is wrong. You need to make use of [`strcpy()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strcpy) to copy elements *into* the array.

Same case apply for `s3[]="}";`, `s2 = strcat(..` kind of statements.

That said, `itoa()` is not a standard `C` function, you should use [`sprintf()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/sprintf) to achieve the same.

A simple two-liner would look like

```
 //assuming steps hold the int value
 char buf[128] ={0};
 sprintf(buf, "{steps: %d }", steps);
```

and then, `buf` will have the value *as* in the required format.